# Git add . Gives me Bus error (core dumped)

Tags: git

I am using ubuntu and trying to put my code on github but when I tried using the "git add ." command , I got an error "Bus error (core dumped)".

```
joannah@joannah-Inspiron-N5040:~/Macerdo$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/joannah/Macerdo/.git/
joannah@joannah-Inspiron-N5040:~/Macerdo$ git add .
Bus error (core dumped)
joannah@joannah-Inspiron-N5040:~/Macerdo$
```

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Bus error is the way the CPU complains about something, like using more SSE registers than the platform actually has. In this context, it's really, really strange. Maybe a compiler bug, maybe compiled for a more recent CPU than the one you are using. What distribution are you using? What is your CPU model?

Comment: This is my CPU information . model           : 37
model name      : Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU        P6200  @ 2.13GHz

Comment: I just rebooted my computer to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved this problem, assuming you can still run `git diff`:

1. Generate a diff patch
2. Remove repo
3. Clone repo again
4. Apply patch

```
git diff --patch > /tmp/patch.diff
cd ..
rm -rf my_repo
git clone <my_repo>
cd my_repo
patch -p1 /tmp/patch.diff
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference .I solved this by creating a new folder and putting all my project files there and when I did a "git add ."  and "git commit" it worked but I still do not know why the former failed to work. The good thing is at least I got a solution and moved on. That is most important. Thanks for the contributions.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `dmesg`. In my case this was due to a hardware error: A bad sector on my disk. :(

This might explain why the command worked after copying the files.

You should find something like this:

```
[ 1387.312569] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x800 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 1387.314589] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 1387.316618] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 1387.318638] ata3.00: cmd 60/08:58:48:1e:54/00:00:12:00:00/40 tag 11 ncq 4096 in
                        res 41/40:00:4b:1e:54/00:00:12:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 1387.322675] ata3.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 1387.324690] ata3.00: error: { UNC }
[ 1387.363352] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 1387.363369] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#11 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1387.363375] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#11 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 1387.363379] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#11 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 1387.363384] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#11 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 12 54 1e 48 00 00 08 00
[ 1387.363388] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 307502667
[ 1387.365427] ata3: EH complete
```

Comment: Actually, I got to know in a few weeks later that time that I had a disk problem. You must be right in this thinking. I cant reproduce this now as I have a new machine.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me quite often since my git repo is mounted via nfs, seems it times out and this causes a bus error sometimes.

The solution I found is to simply remove the lock files and continue on my merry way.

```
find .git -iname *.lock | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a .py file had been corrupted and I got this message every time I tried to add it to a commit.

Deleting the .git / index.lock replaces the damaged file and everything is back to normal.

Comment: You mean `.git/index.lock`, right? If that's `.git` _or_ `index.lock`… deleting your whole `.git` folder erases your whole commit history.