# how to clear Bus error (core dumped) on aws ec2 ubuntu s3 cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I'm using aws ec2 ubuntu and have ssh connection.

All commands entered from ssh connection to s3 produces the error:

```
Bus error (core dumped)
```

Originally, I was trying to do a copy from mybucket to the server:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket ./
```

but the result was the error. Even an ls command produces the error. I don't know how to fix this.

A few days ago, I expanded the system using these [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html#extend-file-system) for ebs volume.

The df -h command produces this:

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root 31G 13G 19G 40% /
devtmpfs 16G 0 16G 0% /dev
tmpfs 16G 8.0K 16G 1% /dev/shm
tmpfs 3.2G 940K 3.2G 1% /run
tmpfs 5.0M 0 5.0M 0% /run/lock
tmpfs 16G 0 16G 0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0 33M 33M 0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/2996
/dev/loop2 98M 98M 0 100% /snap/core/10577
/dev/loop3 98M 98M 0 100% /snap/core/10583
/dev/loop1 34M 34M 0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
/dev/loop4 56M 56M 0 100% /snap/core18/1885
/dev/loop6 56M 56M 0 100% /snap/core18/1944
/dev/loop7 68M 68M 0 100% /snap/lxd/18150
tmpfs 3.2G 0 3.2G 0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs 10M 10M 0 100% /tmp
/dev/loop8 70M 70M 0 100% /snap/lxd/19032
```

and lsblk command produces this:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0 32.3M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/2996
loop1     7:1    0 33.3M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
loop2     7:2    0 97.9M  1 loop /snap/core/10577
loop3     7:3    0 97.9M  1 loop /snap/core/10583
loop4     7:4    0 55.3M  1 loop /snap/core18/1885
loop6     7:6    0 55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1944
loop7     7:7    0 67.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/18150
loop8     7:8    0 69.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/19032
xvda    202:0    0   32G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   32G  0 part /
```

Today, work was proceeding as normal until I entered the command:

```
grep -vf MergedSamplesEdited.vcf ../resources/plink.GRCh37.autosome.map
```

The system `Killed` the process.
I was then able do a few more grep / awk commands, including the one I should have done instead of the grep line above:

```
gawk -F$'\t' 'FNR == NR {a[$6]; next;} {if ($4 in a) {print $0 } }' oldfile.ibd ../resources/plink.GRCh37.autosome.map > newfile.ibd
```

Needing to copy files from s3 bucket, I tried the aws s3 command above and got the bus error.

I searched for a solution and found responses with the bus error, but those responses seemed highly specific and did not apply to my situation. For example, [Git add . Gives me Bus error (core dumped)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26627303/git-add-gives-me-bus-error-core-dumped).

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue and same setup - server restart resolved it for me.

```
$ sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:** check your `/tmp` directory and free up space. `aws` command needs it.

We had experienced this from one of our development servers such that whenever we run any `aws` command results to `Bus error (core dumped)` error message.

We tried to reboot the server to no avail. Eventually, we noticed that the `/tmp` mount was full and some operations on the server are failing as well leading us to `cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device` error message which is basically the best clue that we got.

After clearing up `/tmp` folder, `aws` command run successfully.